# playVideoAt() function in youtube iframe API is not working

Tags: php, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

i have loaded a playlist using cuePlaylist() function in  youtube iframe API.I was using playVideoAt('position') for selecting a particular video in the playlist.

But now playVideoAt() function is not working.Now when i call playVideoAt(), the playlist loaded in the player get disappear and video get stopped after playing the current one. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an issue that was recently filed for this problem -- it does seem to be a recently introduced bug.

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5018&q=playvideoat&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary

If you're in need of a temporary workaround, you could just call 'cuePlaylist' again (or 'loadPlaylist' to have it autoplay) and pass it an index, like this:

```
player.cuePlaylist({'listType':'playlist','list':'[PLAYLIST ID]','index':[VIDEO INDEX NUMBER]});
```

You can test it in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlmcdonald/uz68V/3/

Hopefully it'll be resolved soon.